# getting number of records updated or inserted in sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have an SP that inserts some records and updates others and deletes some. What I want is to return the count values of what was inserted and what was updated and what was deleted.  I thought I could use @@ROWCOUNT but that is always giving me a 1.

After my INSERT I run:

```
PRINT @@ROWCOUNT
```

But my message console shows what really happened and this number:

```
(36 row(s) affected)
1
```

So I can see that 36 records were actually updated but @@ROWCOUNT returned a 1.

I am trying to do the same thing after the UPDATE and DELETE parts of the SP runs with the same result.

Comment: Can you please show your code that includes the insert/update/delete and teh @@rowcount?  My guess is that you are doing something in between, and @@rowcount is only good for the statement following what you want to know the row count affected for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@@ROWCOUNT` will show the number of rows affected by the most recent statement - if you have any statements between the `INSERT` and the `PRINT` then it will give you the wrong number.

Can you show us a little more code so we can see the order of execution?

Comment: DOH!   SET @Inserted = @@ROWCOUNT
 PRINT @@ROWCOUNT - that is my problem - thanks!  pretty silly move.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how @ninesided's answer works for you, you could also use the `output` clause on each update/insert/delete and get the counts from there.

Example:

```
declare @count table
(
    id int
)

update mytable
set oldVal = newVal
output inserted.field1 into @count

select count(*) from @count
```

You could reuse the count table throughout, and set variables as needed to hold the values.